# Windows Phone 7 clear cookies

Tags: silverlight, cookies, browser, windows-phone-7

Is there any possibility to clear cookies generated by WebBrowser control in Silverlight on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2010/09/clearing-cookies-on-windows-phone-7-or.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/1455b8a9-b6f3-47f2-853c-f5eceb812725), cookies cannot be accessed via the API. They can however, be accessed via javascript in an embedded browser (remember to set `.IsScriptEnabled = true`).

To loop through all cookies and deleted thme you could try something like:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    eraseCookies(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
}
```

Or, if eraseCookies doens't work (I haven't checked) you could try:

```
createCookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0], "", -1);
```

Comment: Does this JavaScript code delete all cookies or cookies only from certain domain?

Comment: pass. Have to try it and see.

Comment: It will probably delete the cookies that are available at the current page - I think only those you will get by document.cookie by the web standard. Almost surely you will NOT get cookies from domains that do not match, it'd be kinda security breach. By the way, on OS7.5 there's WebBrowserExtensions class that gives you some access to the cookies.. ..but it's ridiculously and uselessly limited.

Comment: what is the `eraseCookies` function? Is it a default function in the JS or I need to create that function too?

Answer (score 0):

I read this in a blog post yesterday but I can't find the link now.
In short:
1.Create an HttpWebRequest to the server.
2.Attach a cookie collection to it.
3.Keep a reference to this HttpWebRequest throughout your application's lifetime.
4.The cookies of the WebBrowser control will always be reflected in that HttpWebRequest's CookieCollection. When you want to delete them, iterate though that CookieCollection and mark each one of them as Expired.

I am not sure that the above will work, but you can always try.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I came across was actually to immediately log out the user after the initial OAuth2 handshake.

So once I have their final OAuth2 token, I quickly navigate to the logout page, allowing the cookies to be mostly cleared at that time.

Comment: For Facebook at least, this doesn't work (anymore) - once you've logged out, the token no longer seems to work.  I keep track of the user I've authenticated to facebook, and if that changes, I navigate the browser to http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=<login uri returned by FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl()  Maybe its different for other OAuth providers.