# How to clear cookie in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I successful done the **authentication login** part by using `POST` method.

I want to clear the cookie that i obtain in authentication post method when i clicked the `logout button`.

**Any approach to destroy or clear the cookie?**

I have search the resources in `google` but can't find any solution

I also have do the research in **MSDN** about the method of `cookiecontainer` but it don have any method of `clear` and `set expired` in windows phone.

[Clear Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397123/windows-phone-7-clear-cookies)

[Delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647497/how-to-delete-all-cookies-from-windows-phone-webbrowser-control-wp7)

[CookieContainer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app targets Windows Phone 8, there is a new simple API for clearing cookies: [ClearCookiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

No matter which instance of WebBrowser it's called on. 
Sample code:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Here is a tutorial that makes use of it: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application